# Choose profile picture from Cloudinary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloudinary, signing, simple-form-for

I would like to allow my users to choose a picture while they are signing-in.
The thing is I don't want them to take a picture from their own computer. I would like them to choose pictures from a selection from Cloudinary.

Here is my first hypothesis :

I thought about creating a table, this table (name: Blason) could contain all my pictures.
Add a line to my table user, blason_id.
Then when my user sign-in, I add to the simple_form_for, f.select :blason_id ["urlcloudinary"]

Second hypothesis :

Directly through the sign-in form allow them to choose from my selection of pictures from cloudinary. But I don't know how to realize this and by the way if it's possible.

Thank you by advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely create a Blason Model (and the associated table in the DB) with a user_id.
I would seeds all the blasons and use an association input in my User creation `simple_form_for`:

```
<%= f.association :blason, collection: Blason.all.map { |blason| cl_image_tag blason.photo.key }, as: :radio_buttons %>
```

Comment: Hello, I tried this way, but it tells me that the Association is not found with :blason. I put the has_many in the user model and the belongs_to to the blason model. I did a migration in order to add a foreign key on the blason model.

Comment: I finally found out how to display it, but I'm looking for a dropdown list not radio button. I'm gonna check, otherwise if you have an idea

Comment: Try to change `as: radio_buttons` to `as: :select`. You might need to adapt some code tho. Or.. get rid of `as: radio_buttons` altogether. To be tried.

Comment: Hello, I did but if you are using as: :select it shows a drop down menu which is not taking into account the picture. So I decided to go for an other strategy, but thank you